# Story with global mind network

Tags: story-identification

In the eighties I remember reading about a golden band that when worn links everyone in global mental network. Not sure if it was a novel or short story. All thoughts are exposed by this network, which the protagonist finds horribly invasive.

Does anyone know what story this is from?

edit: user **LAK** made a great suggestion in comments but I am not sure this is the one I was looking for. Any other possibilities out there?

Comment: Could you be looking for the same story as in [this older question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28817/trying-to-remember-a-book-where-a-young-man-refuses-to-upload-his-mind-digitally)?

Comment: That looks interesting but this was definitely pre 1990's. And the gold band was integral to the story... had a more "visitor" kind of feeling to it.

Comment: Can you remember anything more about the story you read? Where/when was it set, anything about major characters or events in the plot? You might like to check [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: I am afraid not. Just the golden band, the neural network, the discomfort of the protagonist who was visiting or brought to the culture. I think he gets the hang of it as the story progresses, that is all I can recall. It may not even be the major plot point... It just seems to anticipate the internet so well, would like to read it again.

Comment: The story didn't take place in the distant past, with the golden ring being a torc that amplifies mental power while giving all users, even those with no innate psychic abilities, access to a psychic network?

Comment: @LAK - That sounds pretty promising... I read it ~30 years ago so the details are lost but that certainly jibes with what I recall.

Comment: @rebusB I was referring Julian May's 'Saga of Pliocene Exile' series.  There's a lot more to it than just the bit about the golden torc (though 'The Golden Torc' is the title of one of the books).

Comment: @LAK - Thanks for the recommend, great story in a very interesting setting.  The torc network is close to what I was thinking but the passage that is stuck in my mind never seemed to fully manifest so I am not sure this is the one.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111877/sci-fi-novel-humans-are-slaves-to-aliens-who-enjoy-intoxication-circa-1985-is/111936#111936.

Comment: Nope. Its not about enslavement, but about the neural network enabled by what I remember was a gold head band, and breathing devices were not in the mix. The torc is very similar but I am not convinced its an exact match. Maybe what I am looking for is on the other side of the time divide (Galactic Milieu)?

Comment: @rebusB Glad to hear it!  I figured it was a long shot towards answering your question, which is why I just made it a Comment, rather than an Answer.  The golden torcs only show up in the books set in the distant past.  The 'prequel' Galactic Milieu books which take place in from approximately present day into the future, don't feature the golden torc mind devices at all.

Comment: @rebusB Although if you've now read the Pliocene books, you'll know that I was thinking of the character Bryan, who resists getting a golden torc, because he fears its effects on his individuality.

Comment: @LAK, yeah and there was a moment in the Retort where he starts picking up on others thoughts which may have been the moment. I was kind of expecting Richard (the pilot) to be the one who gets torc'd and had the reaction I remember so vaguely. Good read... next book on hold at library!

Answer (score 5):

This may be Spider Robinson's *Time Pressure* (or one of the other books in the series) which features a global telepathic network mediated by crowns worn by the people.  The viewpoint character in *Time Pressure* is initially very negative about the loss of privacy involved, but gets over it.  Most of the book takes place before the group mind becomes involved, but I think similar issues show up in "Life House"

Previous discussion of this [book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50329/story-about-time-traveler-who-comes-back-to-download-peoples-consciousness-befor/50331#50331)

Comment: Robinson wrote an early short story "Copyright Violation" which included some of these same ideas.

Comment: Thanks- I didn’t know about that one

Comment: Thanks! I will get the book and see if it is the one...

Comment: Finally read the book. While I do remember reading it, and a little bothered looking back at the influence it had on me, it does not have the passage I think I am looking for. Very close. Now to find "Copyright Violation"